# What do the PyMongo docs mean by "sub-collection"?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

[This page in the documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection) says you can access a collection using `c[name]` or `c.name`, where c is a Collection, but what exactly does a sub-collection mean? I couldn't find any use of the term in the mongodb docs.

What I'm assuming, is that it gets the value of each document at key `name`, wihtin the collection, and represents that as its own collection. Is this the case?

Comment: yaps this part of the documentation looks strange since there is no such thing as subcollection in mongoDB.

Comment: Your interpretation can't be valid too since collections have no keys only documents within a collection do.
I asked @jessejiryudavis  for a clarification I am sure he will respond https://twitter.com/nickmilon/status/628219803329626113

Comment: @nickmilon What I meant was that a sub-collection would be the collection obtained by looking up the given key in each document within the collection. So if my collection looked like this: `[{"foo":{"id","1"}}, {"foo":{"id":"2"}}]`, I'd expect its `foo` sub collection to look like this: `[{"id":"1"}, {"id": "2"}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [subcollection](http://srini.karlekar.com/?p=145) is just a naming convention of using `.` in a collection name as a way to organize your collection names.

So with the following code:

```py
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['mydb']
coll = db['test']
subcoll = coll['subtest']
```

`subcoll` is a collection with a name of `test.subtest`.  There's no defined relationship between `test` and `test.subtest`, it's just naming.